# I would like to add new javascript file to my spree extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree, braintree, braintree-rails

I am new in rails. I'm trying to build Spree extension to use Braintree's drop-in UI. I'm trying to add new braintree.js to my extension. These are the steps I did so far.

1. Added `braintree.js` to `<my_extension>/app/assets/javascripts/spree/frontend/`
2. Added `//= require spree/frontend/braintree` to `app/assets/javascripts/spree/frontend/<my_extension>.js`.
3. Created `braintree.rb` in `<my_extension>/config/initializers/`. Content of this file:

   ```
   Braintree::Configuration.environment = :sandbox
   Braintree::Configuration.merchant_id = "merchant_id"
   Braintree::Configuration.public_key = "public_key"
   Braintree::Configuration.private_key = "private_key"
   ```
4. From my spree store I ran `bundle install`, which was successful.
5. Ran `rails g <my_extension>:install` which gives me the following error:

   ```
   append  vendor/assets/javascripts/spree/frontend/all.js
   append  vendor/assets/javascripts/spree/backend/all.js
   insert  vendor/assets/stylesheets/spree/frontend/all.css
   insert  vendor/assets/stylesheets/spree/backend/all.css
   run  bundle exec rake railties:install:migrations FROM=spree_hello_ext 

   from "."
   Would you like to run the migrations now? [Y/n] y
   run  bundle exec rake db:migrate from "."
   rake aborted!
   NameError: uninitialized constant Braintree
   /Users/<user>/Sites/spree_hello_ext/config/initializers/braintree.rb:1:in 
      `<top (required)>'
   /Users/<user>/Sites/hellostore/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
   Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
   (See full trace by running task with --trace)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You need to require the braintree gem in your gemspec as a dependency, and then require it lib/spree_hello_ext.rb for it to be initialized before your initializer tries to use it. Similar to how spree_core it required by spree_gateway:
https://github.com/spree/spree_gateway/blob/master/lib/spree_gateway.rb#L1