# How to add external library to Spree extension?

Tags: external, spree, papaparse

Im'm making my first Spree extension and need to add Papaparse external library ( https://www.papaparse.com ).

I found similar issue ( [I would like to add new javascript file to my spree extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30653965/i-would-like-to-add-new-javascript-file-to-my-spree-extension) ), the re the answer is " You need to require the braintree gem in your gemspec as a dependency", but Papaparse doesn't seems to be as a gem.

I would be grateful for some instructions or resources.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, creating a Spree extension only to load a js file seems overkill, but if you still want to move forward and assuming you want to create an extension for the backend, just download the minified version of PapaParse into app/assets/spree/backend folder inside your extension and add to your spree_papaparse.js the next line

```
//= require_tree .
```

Then, in your project, add to vendor/assets/javascripts/spree/backend/all.js

```
//= require spree/backend/spree_papaparse
```